# Match elements in ListView from one adapter with values from another ListView and adapter

Tags: android, listview

I have the next XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<myxml source-info-url="http://url.com/" source-info-name="URLName" generator-info-url="http://url.org/">
    <tag1 id="92">
        <display-name>1</display-name>
        <icon src="http://some_valid_url.gif" />
    </tag1>
    <tag1 id="107">
        <display-name>2</display-name>
        <icon src="http://some_valid_url.gif" />
    </tag1>
    <tag1 id="175">
        <display-name>3</display-name>
        <icon src="http://some_valid_url.gif" />
    </tag1>
    <tag1 id="346">
        <display-name>4</display-name>
        <icon src="http://some_valid_url.gif" />
    </tag1>
    <tag1 id="357">
        <display-name>5</display-name>
        <icon src="http://some_valid_url.gif" />
    </tag1>


    <tag2 attr1="" attr2="" tag1="92">
        <exampletag1>Text</exampletag1>
        <exampletag2 lang="en">Text</exampletag2>
        <exampletag3 id="21">Text</exampletag3>
        <desc lang="en">Text.</desc>
        <exampletag4>6</exampletag4>
    </tag2>
    <tag2 attr1="" attr2="" tag1="92">
        <exampletag1>&quot;Text&quot;.</exampletag1>
        <exampletag2 lang="en">Text</exampletag2>
    </tag2>
    <tag2 attr1="" attr2="" tag1="92">
        <exampletag1>Text.</exampletag1>
        <exampletag2 lang="en">Text</exampletag2>
    </tag2>

    <tag2 attr1="" attr2="" tag1="107">
        <exampletag1>&quot;Text&quot;.</exampletag1>
        <exampletag2 lang="en">Text</exampletag2>
        <exampletag3 id="22">Text</exampletag3>
        <exampletag3 id="32">Text</exampletag3>
        <exampletag3 id="21">Text</exampletag3>
        <desc lang="en">Text.</desc>
        <exampletag4>6</exampletag4>
    </tag2>
</myxml>
```

`<tag2>` will repeat several thousand times.
`<tag1>` will repeat several hundred times.

I have parsed XML with XMLPullParser, created 2 custom adapters and created 2 ListViews:

```
listView.setAdapter(adapter);//include all of <tag1>
listView2.setAdapter(adapterPr);//include all of <tag2>
```

In activity by default I am showing `listView`, and the `listView2` is `GONE`.

So now I have two ListViews filled with information. Many information.

By clicking on items in `listView` I want to read attribute `<tag1 id="">` and compare it with attribute `<tag2 tag1="107">`.

If comparing succesful - show in `listview2` only items with this ID.

By clicking back button I am returning to `listView` and want to repeat this actions again and again.

**For this I have tried to write the next OnItemClickListener(including commented, also tried without `for`):**

```
    private List<ItemTAG1> items = new ArrayList();
    private List<ItemTAG2> items2 = new ArrayList();
...
    listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                    for(int i=0; i<=items.size(); i++) {
    //                    ItemTAG1 itemTAG1 = adapter.getItem(position);
    //                    ItemTAG2 itemTAG2 = adapter2.getItem(position);
                        ItemTAG1 itemTAG1 = items.get(i);
                        ItemTAG2 itemTAG2 = items2.get(i);

                        String tmpCI = itemTAG1.getTAGId();
                        String tmpPCI = itemTAG2.getTAG2id();

                        if (!tmpCI.equals(tmpPCI)) {
                            listView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                            listViewProgrammes.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        } else {
    //                        adapterPr.remove(item2);
                            Toast.makeText(MyaActivity.this, "No data for this item!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }

                   }
```

But everything what I have tried is wrong and I still can not achieve what I need.

I want to wrote what is happening when I am executing this code, but I understood that I have not done anything for filtering `listView2` from useless items for certain item `listView` and I have no idea what I should do for this.

**How I can compare values and show in `listView2` what I need?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. Inside **ItemTag2** class, add:

   ```
   @Override
   public String toString() {
       return getTAG2id();
   }
   ```
2. Change **OnItemClickListener** to this:

   ```
       listView.setOnItemClickListener(new android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
           ItemTAG1 itemTAG1 = items.get(position);
           String tmpCI = itemTAG1.getTAGId();
           adapter2.getFilter().filter(tmpCI, new Filter.FilterListener() {
               @Override
               public void onFilterComplete(int count) {
                   if(count > 0) {
                       listView2.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                   }else{
                       listView2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                       Toast.makeText(MyaActivity.this, "No data for this item!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                   }

               }
           });
       }
   ```

Hope that helps!

Comment: almost done, but now in listview2 I have a right count of items but this items from listview

Comment: I have wrote wrong information. Issue is the next: in the second item of `listView2` I have elements from the first item of `listView2`. Count of this elements is right, but text is wrong. How I can fix this?

Comment: My wild guess is in getView(), you get data item directly from data list [e.g. ItemTAG2 itemTAG2 = items.get(position);], change it to use getItem() [e.g. ItemTAG2 itemTAG2 = getItem();]. Otherwise, post the adapter code of listView2.

Comment: Yes, you are right, about getting data item directly from data list .`getItem()` needs parameter int - this should be `position`?